# Cloud SQL export table to CLoud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

I need to export a couple of tables from cloudsql to cloud storage . I'm using the [SQLAdmin APIs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/rest) to do the same. I'm following the [guide](https://medium.com/@kennethteh90/how-to-schedule-daily-cloud-sql-export-to-google-cloud-storage-4c1bd360af06) to automate export data from a cloud SQL tables to cloud storage. The table has approximately 5-6 million rows and this needs to be exported to cloud storage bucket daily.

Given that cloud functions have a limit on runtime, Would it be a problem if the export takes longer than 15 mins. Please correct me if I'm not understanding this right.

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be a problem if the export takes longer than 15 mins.

Yes, it would be a problem.  Cloud Functions will forcibly terminate any code that runs past the configured timeout, which means it will not complete.  The max configurable timeout is 9 minutes.

Comment: But @Doug I understand that but I still see a lot of blogs suggesting to use a cloud-functions for backups[https://revolgy.com/blog/how-to-automated-long-term-cloud-sql-backups-step-by-step-guide/] which threw me off a bit.

Comment: Well, you don't have to take the advice of things that won't work for your specific case.